# Split the global arguments of a function?

Tags: regex, list, vim, split

Is there any command in vim that can split the arguments of this function and put them in a list:

```
qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

to get

```
["void *base", "size_t nmemb", "size_t size", "int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)"]
```

The problem is with the last argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the arguments. I ended up by creating the function `GetArguments()` which splits the arguments and put them in the variable `b:list`:

```
function! GetArguments()
                let l:str=getline(".")
                let l:str=substitute(l:str,'^\(\s\|\w\)*\("\|[\|(\|<\|{\)','','')
                let l:str=substitute(l:str,'\("\|]\|)\|>\|}\)\s*\({\|;\)*\s*$','','')
                let l:i=''
                let l:oparen=0
                let l:Arg=""
                let b:list=[]
                for l:i in split(l:str,'\zs')
                        if matchstr(l:i , '\("\|[\|(\|<\|{\)' ) != ''
                                let l:oparen+=1
                        elseif matchstr(l:i , '\("\|]\|)\|>\|}\)' ) != ''
                                let l:oparen-=1
                        endif
                        if matchstr(l:i, ',\|;') == ''
                                let l:Arg=l:Arg.l:i 
                        elseif matchstr(l:i, ',\|;') != '' && l:oparen != 0
                                let l:Arg=l:Arg.l:i
                        elseif matchstr(l:i, ',\|;') != '' && l:oparen == 0
                                if strlen(l:Arg) != 0
                                      call add(b:list,l:Arg)
                                endif
                                let l:Arg=""
                        endif
                endfor
                if strlen(l:Arg) != 0
                        call add(b:list,l:Arg)
                endif 
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [argumentative.vim](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative) you loop though each argument. On each loop you can append the argument to an array and then move to the next argument boundary.

```
command! GetArguments echo GetArguments()
function! GetArguments()
  let reg = @@
  let arr = []
  let view = winsaveview()
  while getline('.')[col('.')-1] != ')'
    normal yi,
    call add(arr, @@)
    normal ],
  endwhile
  let @@ = reg
  call winrestview(view)
  redraw!
  return string(arr)
endfunction
```

Simply place your cursor on the `v` in void in the first argument and run `:GetArguments`. If you want to add the text to the buffer use `:put=GetArguments()`.

Note: I have not tested on any text other than your test text. You may need to modify it to meet your needs.

I am the author of the [argumentative.vim](https://github.com/PeterRincker/vim-argumentative) plugin which works to aid in arguments/parameters manipulation. Argumentative provides the following:

- New text objects, `i,` and `a,`
- Shift arguments via `>,` and `<,`.
- Move to next/previous argument boundaries via `],` and `[,` respectively

I am sure there are other plugins out there that do similar things.

Comment: I ended up by making my own functions finally ! +1

Comment: @Meninx, You may want to share your functions in a post to help others with similar problems

Comment: @Rincker  It is a simple function which did actually what I want at the moment but needs to be improved  !